# Variations in meaning between "Last week" vs. "The last week" vs "The last n weeks"?

Tags: meaning, time, range-inclusion

Similarly between "Last month" and "The last month".

Last week implies, at some point during the *previous* week. Not inclusive of the current week.

What exactly does the last week mean? Is that inclusive of the current time? Same question for the last *n* weeks?

Or are phrases ending with *ago* the only qualifier for being for being inclusive of the current week? *A month ago* pretty obviously implies a period of 30 days going back from current time.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

-**last week** means the week  **preceding** the current one.

-**the last week** refers to a period ending with the week in question , as in:

-*this is the last week I am working.* ( I wil no longer work  after the current  week is finished)

-**the last n weeks** refer to n weeks **preceding** the current one,  as in:

-*I have been working for the last five weeks*, (if the week has just finished it will be considered the fifth week)

Answer (score 3):

I see this mainly as a matter of simple shortening.

- "on the next day"
  can be shortened to
- "the next day"
  and this can become
- "next day"

You can find all three structures in the same text or novel.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those fun ambiguities in modern English that a lot of people struggle with. The same ambiguitiy exists with `next` (e.g., `next week`).

I have not found any rule or concrete standard suggesting that there is a universal rule surrouding the meaning of these phrases. However, I've adopted the following style in order to be more explicit:

When including the current week or month, prefix the phrase with `this`, e.g.:

> This last Tuesday was the 15th of April.
>
> This last week has been quite enjoyable.

You may also be able to avoid ambiguity in the use of `next` with the addition of words like `upcoming` paired with `this`. E.g.:

> This upcoming Monday is tomorrow, whereas next Monday will be the 28th of April.

Again, none of this is standardized (or, therefore, "correct," whatever that means in English), but these modifiers may make the phrases more clear.

Comment: I'm dropping by a decade later to chime in that as a native English speaker, I've never heard/seen, "This last Tuesday was the 15th of April"- it's an awkward construction. If you mean the most recent Tuesday before now, you say, "....last Tuesday" or "...the past Tuesday". The first is more common than the latter. It's strange to hear/see the construction "This last Tuesday". I guess if you really wanted to state it with emphasis-
"When was it?"
"It was this last Tuesday..."

No, actually, on second thought, that's strange no matter what you're up to.

Comment: And it sounds strange to say, "This last week has been quite enjoyable".    It sounds better to say, "This week has been...." or "The past week has been..."